# Light switch using white and black white wires, no ground. What is wrong here?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am replacing an old worn out light switch and it seems to be wired incorrectly. No ground either. Am I wrong?
The switch has been working fine, it just looks bad.

Here is the picture that is worth 1000 words
[image]

Comment: Does the switch itself have a (usually green) ground screw on it?

Comment: Note that an old mechanical (not smart) switch like you've shown doesn't need a ground connection to work.  The ground connection is to protect the user in the event of a short between the hot conductor(s) and metal frame & mounting tabs by making sure external metal parts like the frame are grounded.

Comment: Yes the switch has a ground connector

Comment: Don't know when CEC got rid of them, but NEC was happy with switch loops until 2011 was adopted (long after 2011 some places. Not even yet some places, I think.) So they are utterly common and normal in any house that isn't basically new. If you are working on the wiring in a house that isn't new, you should expect them; if you are remodeling, you may have to upgrade them to /3 for newer codes. Or because you want a switch that needs neutral, even if the work you are doing would not otherwise cause a need to upgrade the cable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is a normal switch loop.  The white wire should be tape black to say it is being used as a hot wire.

The power cable/wires are at the light and the power hot should be connected to that white.

The black goes back to the light connected to the black side.

The white from the light is connected to the white of the power cable.

If the wiring is old enough(before 1970?) then there might not be a ground wire.

Even now you can find lights that do not use ground.  Ground would only be in the box in modern systems.

There does seem to be a small section of ground wire behind that cable.

Comment: Yes there is ground wire wired to the box but not to the switch. Should I add it? The switch installation I structures do say it should be black in black out

Comment: Just connected everything back and it is working.however in my opinion that type of wiring is more prone to problems because the two wires black and white are next to each other

Comment: @MiniMe  The switch should be grounded by the screws.  The only time you can have black in/black out at a switch is when the power goes to the switch first, maybe 50% of the time for light circuits.  Recent code requires a /3 cable if the power goes to the light first, so the switch loop has black, red, and a neutral white(usually capped off and wasted, unless people want a stupid smart switch).

Comment: @MiniMe If the ground wire is wired to the box, then I assume the box is metal, in which case you do not need a ground wire to the switch. The switch will get its grounding when it is screwed into the metal box.

Comment: I color white wires with a sharpie. It *feels* like it lasts better. Tape tends to peel and get in the way. Also, sometimes I just don't do it. In a single gang holding just a switch, there's nothing else the white wire could be.

Comment: @MiniMe since the box is metal, there is no need to bother running a ground wire to the switch.  If you replace any receptacles, buy the $3 "spec grade" receptacles with self-grounding and you won't need ground wires for those either.

Comment: Ah... @Harper-ReinstateMonica... The days of the "$3 spec switch" seem to be gone. The _cheap_ switches (at my home store) are up to $3 now... (Yes, I know, I should be buying at a local electrical supplier, but they're out of stock on a lot of things...)

Answer (score 21):

This is a **metal box**. Those are better.

With metal boxes, the ground wires should go **to the metal box first**.

With switches in metal boxes, there is no need for a ground wire to the switch, as it will pick up ground via the mounting screws.

The grounding looks exactly correct in this box.

Now, if it was a receptacle instead, the grounding requirement is more demanding.  It needs hard metal contact between receptacle frame and metal box, or a special switch frame called "Self-Grounding" which has wipers which do a better job contacting the mounting screw.

---

---

The single cable with black/white pair is called a **switch loop**.  It is a normal and common, though obsolete, way of connecting a switch. You can search the web for how switch loops work.

The white wire is always-hot.  The black wire is switched-hot.  It will be difficult to put a smart switch here.

Note that the existing switch is a 3-way switch and the 3rd non-ground screw is not used.  You can replace that with a regular switch.

If you want quality, spring for the $3 version of the switch.

Comment: You *can* connect the neutral of a smart switch to the ground, but probably shouldn't. The alternative is running another wire to the switch box, just for the neutral.

Comment: @19565 OP didn't mention a smart switch, but good intuition.  Connecting smart switch neutral to ground is a code violation, UNLESS, you are dealing with one of the minority of smart switches which is actually UL-Listed to do that.  UL will allow it if the device bootlegs less than 0.5mA normally, and is built to be impossible to draw more than 5-10 mA or so (to avoid shocking people if the device has a problem). That's not enough to transmit WiFi, so those devices include a battery or large cap.

Comment: The photo appears to show a bare ground wire going mostly-horizontal that is likely properly connected to the box.

Comment: yes there is a ground wire connected to the box. I just added a copper wire between the box and the switch not realizing that the screws do that.

Comment: @minime that's fine as long as you did not break the mandatory connection between incoming cable and metal box.  I.E. *don't* move the ground to the device.

Comment: no way I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just another point that I didn't see mentioned here: Back in the days before NMC ("non-metallic conduit", the double-insulated cables now used), wiring was often done with single wires fed through tubing (conduit). In those installations, it was common to treat the conduit as the safety ground path rather than running an additional ground wire.

I live in a house with some wiring of this sort,and every electrical box is properly grounded that way even with no separate ground wire.

Note that If you *really* have no safety ground, but need a three-prong outlet, you should install a GFCI. These don't rely on having ground available, and are a fair safer option than other ways of trying to make a three-prong plug work in a two-wire outlet.

Comment: "back in the days..."? Visit Chicago and poke behind the cover plate. They _require_ conduit in every installation, commercial _and_ residential. It's still common to treat metal conduit as ground and save money pulling an extra wire. Additionally, the OP is asking about replacing a switch, not an outlet - your last paragraph is correct, but not applicable.

Comment: True enough. I should edit.